# Magit diff working file to commit in log?

Tags: magit, git, ediff

How does one ediff a current file--ie working tree--against an arbitrary version in some previous commit?

In this case, I'm interested in pulling in some, but not all, changes from a commit in another feature branch that was rejected.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a one-step way to do this.  The best I can come up
with is

- Type <kbd>dr</kbd> (`magit-diff`), and set the range to the commit

  If point is on the commit, you can copy it with <kbd>C-w</kbd>
  before calling <kbd>dr</kbd>.
- In the diff buffer, go to the file you want and hit <kbd>e</kbd>
  (`magit-ediff-dwim`)

Though you might consider doing away with the ediff step.  You can hit
<kbd>v</kbd> to reverse a hunk at point in the working tree.

Comment: The twist is that the commit is in another branch; can you reverse from a commit not in the current one?

Comment: Did you try?  When you enter a commit for a range, the diff shows the changes between that commit and the working tree (with the working tree changes treated as new).

Comment: Notably, you can now use `C-x l` from the `magit-diff` transient state to enable the `-R` option that reverses old and new, so that you get the diff in the order you want if you're pulling in changes selectively.